# Compare size of a local file to a file on a webserver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, server

Suppose I has a file named *fileA.txt* in my web server in the directory:

```
www.example.com/updates/
```

And in my computer i have a file named *fileB.txt* in the location:

```
D:Pycodes/file/
```

How do I create a Python program on Windows 10 Python IDLE to check whether the size of fileA is equal to the size of fileB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library to get the size of the remote file by getting the headers and checking `content-length`

```
import requests
remote_size = requests.head(
    'http://www.example.com/updates/fileA.txt').headers['content-length']
```

To get the size of your local file:

```
import os
local_size = os.path.getsize('D:/Pycodes/file/fileB.txt')
```

Then you can compare the two